# Problem with relationship retreival Neo4j

Tags: database, graph, neo4j

I have a deep relationship with multiple nodes. I want to create unique relationships between the items. I tried usage of IDs, but it did not help me a lot. What is the best way to create unique relationship between node with intersection between other nodes?

This is a type of a relationship which I have
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKdtb.jpg

`MATCH r = (t)-[:HAS_FIELD]->(:Field {name: "Title"})-[:ON_LANGUAGE]->(:Language)-[:HAS_TRANSLATION]->(:Translation)`

This is the code which I have to retrieve the relationship between the highest node (Green One) to the lowest (Gray one).

The biggest obstacle is that I want to retreive unique relationship between the node - One Green, One Purple, One Dark Green, and One Gray. But instead of this, I receive all relationships, like you see on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way.
I just simply add IDs of the topic to each relationship, so later on I will easy get the unique ones.

`(topic)-[:HAS_FIELD]->(f)-[:ON_LANGUAGE]->(l)-[:HAS_TRANSLATION {id: t.id}]->(tr)`